# Ubuntu 10.04: mysqldump: command not found and wouldn't install mysql-client

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysqldump

Some packages have gone missing from my Ubuntu server and few things are not working because of that.

When I try to install `mysql-client` I get this error:

```
# sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libauthen-pam-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libdbi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libio-pty-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libperl5.14 : Depends: perl-base (= 5.14.2-13) but 5.10.1-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libsub-name-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libtext-charwidth-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.14.2-3) but 5.10.1-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
                          Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libtext-iconv-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.14.2-5) but 5.10.1-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 mysql-client : Depends: mysql-client-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-client-5.1 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) but 5.1.41-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
                    Depends: libmysqlclient16 (>= 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) but 5.1.41-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-client-core-5.1 (>= 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) but 5.1.41-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.14.2-13) but 5.10.1-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I run apt-get -f install get following error.

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ifupdown initscripts libdbd-mysql-perl liblocale-gettext-perl mysql-common mysql-server netbase perl-base rsyslog
9 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 2 to remove and 172 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 64.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = (unset)
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Text/Iconv/Iconv.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
(Reading database ... 43650 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-client-5.5 (from .../mysql-client-5.5_5.5.24+dfsg-8_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.24+dfsg-8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mysqlcheck', which is also in package mysql-client-core-5.1 5.1.41-3ubuntu12
configured to not write apport reports
                                      dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.24+dfsg-8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you try `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: @m4573r yes, i updated the answer error message i get when I run apt-get -f install

Comment: try install localepurge. it should run immediately after install and you can select the languages you want to be available on the system. it looks like some are missing.

Comment: also have you recently changes your sources.list file?

Comment: I didn't change that and installing localepurge also gives error.  # sudo apt-get install localepurge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.1 : Depends: mysql-client-5.1 (>= 5.1.41-3ubuntu12) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).